# Compute $\mathbb{E}(X|X+Y)$ for $X, Y$ IID standard exponential

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

How to find the random variable $\mathbb{E}(X|X+Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are IID exponential random variables with parameter $1$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of conditional expectance?

Comment: yea conditional expectation E(X|X+Y) is the random variable that is measurable with respect to σ(X+Y) and E(XI_{A}) = E(E(X|X+Y)I_{A}) for all A in σ(X+Y)?

Comment: It's a good one. I'm not sure how to proceed but as it stands, the joint distribution of $X$ and $X+Y$ seems to be hard to compute since $\mathbb{E}[X(X+Y)]\ne 0$. Any progress?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Compare $E[X\mid X+Y]$ and $E[Y\mid X+Y]$. Compute $E[X+Y\mid X+Y]$. Conclude.

Thus, the result uses only that $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. (and integrable), not their exact distribution. To be more precise, the result uses only that $(X,Y)$ is *exchangeable*, that is, that the random vectors $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ have the same distribution.

Comment: That makes sense, but how would you check that 0.5(X + Y) satisfies the second condition of Conditional Expectation?

Comment: Pretty much using the same remark, why? Did you try to check this and did you run into a problem of some sort? (Note that this verification is not needed, the approach in my post being self-sufficient.)

Comment: Nevermind I was able to show it. THank you very much!!!