# Expectation of a discrete random variable

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, binomial-distribution

Let $X$, $Y$ $\sim Binomial(n, p)$ and are independent.

One needs to calculate $\mathrm{E}[X|X+Y=m]$.

I've calculated the formula of $\mathrm{P}(X+Y=m)$:
$$\mathrm{P}(X+Y=m) = \binom{2n}{m} p^m (1-p)^{2n-m}$$

I know that $$E[X|X+Y=m] = \sum_{x=0}^{m}x\mathrm{P}(X=x|X+Y=m)=\sum_{x=0}^{m}x\frac{\mathrm{P}(X=x,X+Y=m)}{\mathrm{P}(X+Y=m)}\text{ .}$$

I'm not sure if there's an easier way but I have no idea how to represent any of the written probabilities in the expression of conditional expectation. So, my question is how to solve this last step?

Comment: Hint: The event $(X=a, X+Y = b)$ is the same event as $(X=a,Y=b-a)$. Further (although your statement doesn't say it), I guess we must assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent, no?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independant?

Comment: For a simpler (and more general) approach, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602210/exxy-x-y-iid-exp-1

Comment: OP: Would you know how to justify the symmetry argument in the accepted answer?

Comment: Is it enough that $E[X+Y] = E[X] + E[Y]$, regardless of (condition) what is known?

Comment: Absolutely not.

Comment: If you do not know how to justify the symmetry argument in the accepted answer, why did you accept it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what answer you expect, since $X$, $Y$ are independent and of same distribution, just symbolically it is clear that $E[X | X+Y = m ] = E[Y | X+Y = m ] = E[X | X+X=m]$.

Comment: Well, the first identity is the argument (which is not "symbolic" in the least), the second one is absurd. (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is an easier way.

If $X$ and $Y$ are identically and independently distributed then by symmetry $$E[X\mid X+Y=m] =E[Y\mid X+Y=m] =\frac12 E[X+Y\mid X+Y=m] = \dfrac{m}{2}. $$